# What is the easiest method to print some strings and two pictures?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, printing

I have to do some quick & dirty job today.
I need to send to the printer some strings, an empty line, and then two bitmaps.
Always in an A4.

Are there any easy method to send this data to the printer? I don't want to make a report.

Comment: Did you invest any time in .NET's printing API?

Comment: @VVS: No, I've never need it before. :(

Comment: Take a look ant this Beginner's Guide to Printing in .NET. It's not so hard when you got it. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27404/An-absolute-beginner-s-guide-to-printing-in-NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could code a html page that includes your texts and links to pictures and then print it.

Answer (score 2):

Create document as html. 
Load document in [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d67hf8a.aspx). 
Send to [printer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.print.aspx)